# c++ passing an object as function parameter to a function expecting an std::optional

Tags: c++, compilation, c++17

I have a function `func(std::optional<A>& a)` and I want to call it using an instance of `A` like in this code:

```
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    explicit A(int a) : m_a(a)
    {}

    ~A() = default;

    int get() { return m_a; }

    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(A&&) = delete;

private:
    int m_a;
};

void func(std::optional<A>& a)
{
    if (a.has_value()) {
        std::cout << a->get() << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "no value" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    A a(5);
    func(a);
}
```

As you can see, `A` does not allow for any copy or move operators. When I run this code I get

```
<source>:34:10: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::optional<A>&' from 
expression of type 'A'
```

My question is how can I pass `a` to `func()` and make the `std::optional` reference my object?

If that's not possible, I would still like to have a way to pass `a` to `func()` not using c-style pointers (`func(A* a)` for example)

Comment: I believe it's not possible. `std::optional<A>` cannot own/manage an externally-provided object (`a` in your case). It can own a new object created by copying/moving content from `a`, but this is explicitly disallowed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If another layer of indirection is not a problem you can use a `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<A>>` :

```
#include <functional>

//.... 

void func(const std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<A>>& a)
{
    if (a.has_value()) {
        std::cout << a->get().get() << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "no value" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    A a(5);
    func(std::ref(a));
}
```

(I suppose the missing `const` was a typo, because it would be an error in your example too even if `A` could be moved or copied).

Note that this does meet your requirements: Pass a `std::optional` and not use raw pointers. However, it is a little weird to use a reference (instead of pointer) because it cannot be null and then wrap that into an optional to allow "null" values. Using a raw pointer seems to be the most simple and straight forward solution.

Note that raw pointers are not "c-style". What can be considered c-style and what should be avoided by all means is raw owning pointers. When you want to pass a parameter to a function, and the function does not interfere with ownership, and it can either have a value or not a value then a raw pointer is just fine. Just do

```
void func(A* a)
{
    if (a) {
        std::cout << a->get() << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "no value" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    A a(5);
    func(&a);
}
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the awkward double-get is only necessary because of the one-liner, since `*a` implicitly converts to `A&`. e.g. `A& a_ref = *a;` works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Frank good point, what I actually wanted to say is that its "another layer of indirection"

Comment: It seems to be a viable solution, though, generally, it seems to me that an _optional reference wrapper_ does not make much sense. Basically, it is just a more complicated (raw) pointer.

Comment: @DanielLangr indeed its a little odd to use a reference instead of pointer to avoid null values and then pack that into an `optional` to allow null values. Though, I think it meets OPs requirements. For some reason they want to avoid raw pointers. ( on second read there might be some misunderstanding, also because they call it "c-style pointers"). WIll try to clarify

Comment: I personally really like this idiom from a semantics PoV. If the standard library had specializations so that `sizeof(optional<reference_wrapper<T>>) == sizeof(void*)`, I could see myself actually using it, particularly for member variables. (probably through an alias, though).